# ClassNotFoundException while trying to deploy spring ws + saaj webapp on JBoss EAP 6.3

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-ws, saaj

I'm trying to deploy our web application (which works fine in Tomcat 7) on JBoss EAP 6.3 but I'm receiving the following ClassNotFoundException upon deployment

```
15:49:21,953 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/xxx-webapp]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/appCtx-xxx-remoting-ws.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl#6f47288' of type [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl] while setting bean property 'messageFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl] for bean with name 'com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl#6f47288' defined in class path resource [spring/appCtx-xxx-remoting-ws.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl from [Module "deployment.xxx-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) [spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472) [spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl] for bean with name 'com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl#6f47288' defined in class path resource [spring/appCtx-xxx-remoting-ws.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl from [Module "deployment.xxx-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl from [Module "deployment.xxx-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258) [spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
```

The SaajSoapMessageFactory is configured to use the SAAJ implementation provided by the Oracle JDK

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"> 
  <property name="messageFactory">
     <bean class="com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

We are not bundling any SAAJ implementation in our .war file. Looks like JBoss is somehow preventing that the class is loaded from the JDK.

I played around with various jboss-deployment-structure.xml setups so far but until now to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for fix this I had to do the following

add the following dependency to my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

change the spring bean definition of the messageFactory to the following

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"> 
  <property name="messageFactory">
     <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the WEB-INF folder of the .war file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
      <!--    
      we want to use the saaj module provided by JBoss 
      it looks like we can't use the implementation provided by the JDK - JBoss somehow does not seem to allow it
      -->
         <module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I have the similar problem with websphere? Do you have any idea on how to resolve this on websphere?

Comment: We've also successfully deployed our application on websphere but the correct solution totally depends on your setup I'd suggest to create a new question for that. If I recall correctly we are using the "messageFactory" documented in my question and had to remove xerces in order to get it running but I'd have to check.